# Modify gradient in TensorFlow backward pass

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to modify the gradients for all layers in TensorFlow with a custom gradient, and also save the current gradient. Conceptually, the computation process for a single layer in the *i*-th iteration looks like:

1. `original_grad = (actual gradient computed by TF)`
2. `custom_grad = f(original_grad, stored_grad[i - 1])`
3. `stored_grad[i] = original_grad`
4. Use `custom_grad` to update layer weights

I'm pretty new to TF so quite lost on how / whether this could be achieved.

Answer (score 3):

For answering your question, we must look at what optimizers usually do when you call `optimizer.minimize(loss)`.

Actually they are performing two subsequent operations: `compute_gradients()` and `apply_gradients`.

From [Tensorflow documentation of tf.train.Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer), we read:

> Calling `minimize()` takes care of both computing the gradients and applying them to the variables.

So:

> If you want to process the gradients
>   before applying them you can instead use the optimizer in three steps:
>
> 1. Compute the gradients with `compute_gradients()`.
> 2. Process the gradients as you wish.
> 3. Apply the processed gradients with `apply_gradients()`.

Directly from the documentation I can take an example of applying some modifications to the gradients:

```
# Create an optimizer.
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

# Compute the gradients for a list of variables.
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, <list of variables>)

# grads_and_vars is a list of tuples (gradient, variable).  Do whatever you
# need to the 'gradient' part, for example cap them, etc.
capped_grads_and_vars = [(MyCapper(gv[0]), gv[1]) for gv in grads_and_vars]

# Ask the optimizer to apply the capped gradients.
opt.apply_gradients(capped_grads_and_vars)
```